# Main thread and worker thread initialization

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, libc

I'm creating a multi-thread program in C and I've some troubles.
There you have the function which create the threads :

```
void        create_thread(t_game_data *game_data)
{
  size_t    i;
  t_args    *args = malloc(sizeof(t_args));

  i = 0;
  args->game = game_data;
  while (i < 10)
    {
      args->initialized = 0;
      args->id = i;
      printf("%zu CREATION\n", i);//TODO: Debug
      pthread_create(&game_data->object[i]->thread_id, NULL, &do_action, args);
      i++;
      while (args->initialized == 0)
          continue;
    }
}
```

Here you have my args struct :

```
typedef struct      s_args
{
  t_game_data       *object;
  size_t            id;
  int               initialized;

}args;
```

And finally, the function which handle the created threads

```
void        *do_action(void *v_args)
{
  t_args    *args;
  t_game_data   *game;
  size_t    id;
  args = v_args;
  game = args->game;
  id = args->id;
  args->initialized = 1;

[...]

  return (NULL);
}
```

The problem is :

The main thread will create new thread faster than the new thread can init his variables :

```
args = v_args;
game = args->game;
id = args->id;
```

So, sometime, 2 different threads will get same `id` from `args->id`.
To solve that, I use an variable `initialized` as a bool so make "sleep" the main thread during the new thread's initialization.

But I think that is really sinful.
Maybe there is a way to do that with a mutex? But I heard it wasn't "legal" to unlock a mutex which does not belong his thread.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution should work in theory except for a couple of major problems.

- The main thread will sit spinning in the while loop that checks the flag using CPU cycles (this is the least bad problem and can be OK if you know it won't have to wait long)
- Compiler optimisers can get trigger happy with respect to empty loops. They are also often unaware that a variable may get modified by other threads and can make bad decisions on that basis.
- On multi core systems, the main thread may never see the change to `args->initiialzed` or at least not until much later if the change is in the cache of another core that hasn't been flushed back to main memory yet.

You can use John Bollinger's solution that mallocs a new set of args for each thread and it is fine. The only down side is a malloc/free pair for each thread creation. The alternative is to use "proper" synchronisation functions like Santosh suggests. I would probably consider this except I would use a semaphore as being a bit simpler than a condition variable.

A semaphore is an atomic counter with two operations: wait and signal. The wait operation decrements the semaphore if its value is greater than zero, otherwise it puts the thread into a wait state. The signal operation increments the semaphore, unless there are threads waiting on it. If there are, it wakes one of the threads up.

The solution is therefore to create a semaphore with an initial value of 0, start the thread and wait on the semaphore. The thread then signals the semaphore when it is finished with the initialisation.

```
#include <semaphore.h>

// other stuff

sem_t semaphore;
void create_thread(t_game_data *game_data)
{
     size_t    i;
     t_args    args;

     i = 0;
     if (sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0) == -1) // third arg is initial value
     {
         // error
     }
     args.game = game_data;
     while (i < 10)
     {
         args.id = i;
         printf("%zu CREATION\n", i);//TODO: Debug
         pthread_create(&game_data->object[i]->thread_id, NULL, &do_action, args);
         sem_wait(&semaphore);
         i++;
    }
    sem_destroy(&semaphore);
}

void *do_action(void *v_args) {
    t_args *args = v_args;
    t_game_data *game = args->game;
    size_t    id = args->id;
    sem_post(&semaphore);

    // Rest of the thread work

    return NULL;
}
```

Because of the synchronisation, I can reuse the args struct safely, in fact, I don't even need to malloc it - it's small so I declare it local to the function.

Having said all that, I still think John Bollinger's solution is better for this use-case but it's useful to be aware of semaphores generally.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that!
It looks amazing!
Thanks

Comment: Just a question, put the args in stack won't be a problem with the threads?

Comment: @LightMan No, because all the threads share the same address space including the space used by the main process's stack. However, you do have to make sure that the threads have finished with the struct before the function exits (the semaphore does that).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution to this problem would be to pass a different `t_args` object to each new thread.  To do that, move the allocation inside the loop, and make each thread responsible for freeing its own argument struct:

```
void create_thread(t_game_data *game_data) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        t_args *args = malloc(sizeof(t_args));

        if (!args) {
            /* ... handle allocation error ... */
        } else {
            args->game = game_data;
            args->id = i;
            printf("%zu CREATION\n", i);//TODO: Debug
            if (pthread_create(&game_data->object[i]->thread_id, NULL,
                    &do_action, args) != 0) {
                // thread creation failed
                free(args);
                // ... 
            }
        }
    }
} 

// ...

void *do_action(void *v_args) {
    t_args *args = v_args;
    t_game_data *game = args->game;
    size_t    id = args->id;

    free(v_args);
    args = v_args = NULL;

    // ...

    return (NULL);
}
```

But you also write:

> To solve that, I use an variable initialized as a bool so make "sleep"
>   the main thread during the new thread's initialization.
>
> But I think that is really sinful. Maybe there is a way to do that
>   with a mutex? But I heard it wasn't "legal" to unlock a mutex which
>   does not belong his thread.

If you nevertheless wanted one thread to wait for another thread to modify some data, as your original strategy requires, then you must employ either  atomic data or some kind of synchronization object.  Your code otherwise contains a data race, and therefore has undefined behavior.  In practice, you cannot assume in your original code that the main thread will *ever* see the new thread's write to `args->initialized`.  "Sinful" is an unusual way to describe that, but maybe appropriate if you belong to the Church of the Holy C.

You could solve that problem with a mutex by protecting just the test of `args->initialized` in your loop -- not the whole loop -- with a mutex, and protecting the threads' write to that object with the same mutex, but that's nasty and ugly.  It would be far better to wait for the new thread to increment a semaphore (not a busy wait, and the `initialized` variable is replaced by the semaphore), or to set up and wait on a condition variable (again not a busy wait, but the `initialized` variable or an equivalent is still needed).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in `create_thread` you are passing the same `t_args` structure to each thread.  In reality, you probably want to create your own t_args structure for each thread.

What's happening is your 1st thread is starting up with the args passed to it.  Before that thread can run `do_action` the loop is modifying the args structure.  Since thread2 and thread1 will both be pointing to the same args structure, when they run `do_action` they will have the same id.

Oh, and don't forget to not leak your memory

Comment: This is not the answer. The code in the question has a loop `while (args->initialized == 0) continue;` which the OP thinks should stop the main thread until the child thread has set args->initialised. To be fair, I don't think the question is particularly clear.

Comment: Yeeeks.  I totally missed that.  Was not expecting that to be there.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using condition variable for this. You can find an example here http://maxim.int.ru/bookshelf/PthreadsProgram/htm/r_28.html.
Basically wait in the main thread and signal in your other threads.

Comment: Somebody has down voted your answer, probably because you haven't provided much detail. Why use a condition variable?